# MultiValueDictKeyError with modified inline template in Django admin

Tags: python, django

In Django 1.11, I have 2 models, `Foo` and `Bar`:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

class Bar(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    foo = models.ForeignKey(Foo)
```

My `admin.py` looks like this:

```
class BarInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Bar
    template = 'admin/edit_inline/list.html'

class FooAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = ('name')
    inlines = [BarInline]
```

I use a customised template to show the `Bar` inline form, because I don't want the forms, just links to the edit pages for each `Bar`. `list.html` looks like this:

```
{% load i18n admin_urls static %}
<div class="js-inline-admin-formset inline-group" data-inline-type="stacked">
<fieldset class="module {{ inline_admin_formset.classes }}">
  <h2>{{ inline_admin_formset.opts.verbose_name_plural|capfirst }}</h2>
{{ inline_admin_formset.formset.management_form }}
{% for inline_admin_form in inline_admin_formset %}<div class="inline-related{% if inline_admin_form.original or inline_admin_form.show_url %} has_original{% endif %}{% if forloop.last %} empty-form last-related{% endif %}">
  <h3 style="overflow:auto"><span style="float:left">{{ inline_admin_formset.opts.verbose_name|capfirst }}:&nbsp;{% if inline_admin_form.original %}<a href="{% url inline_admin_form.model_admin.opts|admin_urlname:'change' inline_admin_form.original.pk|admin_urlquote %}">{{ inline_admin_form.original }}</a>{% else %}#{{ forloop.counter }}{% endif %}</span><span style="float:right">{% if inline_admin_form.original %}<a href="{% url inline_admin_form.model_admin.opts|admin_urlname:'change' inline_admin_form.original.pk|admin_urlquote %}" class="inlinechangelink">Change</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="{% url 'admin:app_bar_delete' inline_admin_form.original.pk|admin_urlquote %}" class="deletelink">Delete</a>{% endif %}</span>
  </h3>
</div>{% endfor %}
<div class="add-row">
    <a href="{% url 'admin:app_bar_add' %}?foo={{original.pk}}">Add a Bar</a>
</div>
</fieldset>
</div>
```

The problem is that when I edit an existing `Foo`, and click `Save`, I get the error:

> MultiValueDictKeyError at /admin/app/foo/1/change/
>
> "'bar_set-0-id'"

EDIT: [Stacktrace](https://pastebin.com/raw/C3fSCH2D)

Comment: Can you add the full stacktrace?

Comment: @markwalker_Done!

Comment: I don't understand why you're using inlines if you don't want the inline forms. Why don't you just output the links directly?

Comment: @DanielRoseman Chalk it up to inexperience! Plus I liked the formatting of the inline form.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the form for the inline, the easiest approach is to not make the field(s) editable. This will render the objects with their values, but not editable in a form. The other way to display this is `admin.TabularInline`.

The options for inlines can be found here; https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-options

The option that you will likely want to enable is [`show_change_link`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.InlineModelAdmin.show_change_link)

What you'd end up with is something like;

```
class BarInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Bar
    fields = ('name', )
    readonly_fields = ('name', )
    show_change_link = True
```

Comment: This has the disadvantage that when you click Add a Bar, it will not display the form anywhere. I am leaning towards @Daniel Roseman's solution of modifying the template to output links.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested, I ended up extending the template. I created a file `change_form.html` in `templates/admin/app/foo/`, and overrode the `after_related_objects` block:

```
{% extends 'admin/change_form.html' %}
{% load admin_urls %}
{% block after_related_objects %}
<div class="js-inline-admin-formset inline-group">
    <fieldset class="module">
        {% for bar in original.bar_set.all %}
            <h3>
                {{ bar.name }}
                <a href="{% url 'admin:app_bar_change' bar.pk|admin_urlquote %}">Change</a>
            </h3>
        {% endfor %}
    </fieldset>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```